Double slit experiment: What does it mean by observing or measuring? What's the difference?
When we talk about double slit experiment, there is duality in nature. There is a novel, a brief history of time from the Big Bang to black hole by(Stephen Hawking) where I heard about it, and when I research in a blog I read that when we observe it behaves like particle when we don't behave like waves.
When I do little bit of research, so I read by observing it means by measuring in the discipline of quantum physics, so I don't understand what does it actually mean does it mean if I actually looking it behave like particle and if I stop looking at it, it behave like waves or it means something else.

Actually: it always behaves like waves.
When we observe it going through a slit, there is a diffraction pattern, which is a wave thing that is a coherent sum over going through all possible positions in the slit.
If we have two slits, but we record which one it goes through, we get the incoherent sum of two diffraction patterns; that is, the two waves add energies, but not amplitudes--there is no interference. Note that this implies we fire many particles--each independently go through one slit, and there is no mechanism for interference (other than diffraction$^1$).
When we don't observe which slit it goes through,
we need to add the two diffraction patterns' amplitudes. That gives
an interference pattern modulating two diffraction patterns, which is a coherent sum over going through all possible positions in both slits.
It is always a coherent sum over all possible paths, no matter what the aperture pattern is.
[1] Note that going through one slit of width $d$ is the limit of going through two slits of width $d/2$ as their separation goes to zero.

Your answer forgot to treat the case where we observe which of the two slits it goes through.

@naturallyInconsistent The first paragraph is "when we go through one slit", which is valid regardless of the number of other slits not being traversed.

that's why I did not accuse you of failing to cover the single slit diffraction. Still, it is clear that the OP would be much better served with a direct treatment of the double slit with observation of which slit was traversed, and it is easy to incorporate into your solution.
